# How to assign additional keys to a set of objects

Tags: python, django

I am using a Detail View generic and I am trying to add an attribute to each item for a group of Comments (The detail view is for a Post that has many comments). I am trying to loop through the group of comments and assign a boolean to a new attribute is_liked_by_user. When I try to print comment.is_liked_by_user it will show in the scope of it but when I try to find it in the context['post'] I get this error *** AttributeError: 'Comment' object has no attribute 'is_liked_by_user'. What is the correct way to assign this attribute so that it can be passed to my template?

```
class DetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/detail.html'
    form_class = CommentsForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            # Call the base implementation first to get the context
            context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            # Create any data and add it to the context
            context['form'] = self.form_class
            post = context['post']
            comments = post.comment_set.all()
            for i, comment in enumerate(comments):

              comment.is_liked_by_user = check_existing_dictionary_in_list(comment.reactions.all(), "user", self.request.user)
              print("Was comment liked by user?", comment.is_liked_by_user, comment.comment_body)
                # comment.is_liked_by_user = check_existing_dictionary_in_list(comment.reactions.all(), "user", self.request.user)
                # context['is_liked_by_user'] = check_existing_dictionary_in_list(post.reactions.all(), "user", self.request.user)
            pdb.set_trace()
            return context
```

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_body = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    like_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField('date created', null=True, auto_now_add=True,blank=True )
    reactions = GenericRelation(Reaction)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment_body
```

Comment: Would you mind showing your `models` or at least the `Comment` model

Comment: Adding the `is_liked_by_user` attribute would probably work better as an annotation

Comment: @crazychukz Yeah I just edited it to include the model for Comment.

Comment: @IainShelvington I'm not sure how to annotate the post.comment_set and how would I assign a boolean for them?